# problems with reading input and storing it in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Hi I have an algorithm which should read user input save it in an array and count letters used A used 3 b used 3 .....
but my algorithm does not work with 1 , 3 , any odd number and work with 2, 4, even numbers..
Any ideas how to fix this error 
Thanks guys for help 
code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int i = 0;
    char c;
  int counta = 0;
        int countb = 0;
        int countc = 0;
        int countd = 0;
        char [] array = new char [4];
        array[0]='a';
        array[1]='b';
        array[2]='c';
        array[3]='d';

    while (reader.read()!='\n') {
        int x = 1+i;
        char[] cbuf = new char[x];
        c = (char) reader.read();
        cbuf[i] = c;

               if (cbuf[i]==array[0]){
               counta++;
               }
               if (cbuf[i]==array[1]){
               countb++;
               }
               if (cbuf[i]==array[2]){
               countc++;
               }
               if (cbuf[i]==array[3]){
               countd++;
               }
          System.out.println(cbuf);

                i++;

        }
```

Comment: post your implementation first , then ask for help

Comment: Obviously you are reading twice on every iteration. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arise since you are reading twice on every iteration.

```
c = (char) reader.read();
while (c!='\n') {
    int x = 1+i;
    char[] cbuf = new char[x];
    cbuf[i] = c;

           if (cbuf[i]==array[0]){
           counta++;
           }
           if (cbuf[i]==array[1]){
           countb++;
           }
           if (cbuf[i]==array[2]){
           countc++;
           }
           if (cbuf[i]==array[3]){
           countd++;
           }
      System.out.println(cbuf);

            i++;

    c = (char) reader.read(); //read once on every iteration

    }
```

Comment: Yury Tarabanko 
Thank you very much it works 
i was really stupid though that i made such mistake
Anyway Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Each time your program executes `reader.read()`, it will read a character.  In your `while` loop, it executes `reader.read()` every time it loops back, so that it can check for `\n`.  But you don't save the result; when you then say

```
`c = reader.read()`;
```

it reads a **new** character; it doesn't use the one that it already tested in the `while` expression.

You need to arrange things to that it only reads once.  Two possibilities (there are others):

```
while ((c = reader.read()) !='\n') {
    // other code
    // GET RID OF THIS LINE c = (char) reader.read();
```

or

```
while (true) {
    c = (char) reader.read();
    if (c == '\n') {
        break;
    }
    // other code
    // and so on
```

This won't fix other errors in your code; it's just showing you a couple ways you can avoid calling a function twice in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling reader.read() twice, once in the loop conditional and then to assign to 'c'. The first time results in the buffer being read and 'wasted', therefore ~half the bytes are skipped. You may define 'c' outside the loop and then use

```
while ((c = reader.read()) != '\n') {
```

On a non-related note, consider using an array of 'counts' to hold the counts - it's usually the preferred way over defining four separate variables (counta, countb, countc, countd will be replaced with an int array counts[4].) You could then do:

```
counts[c-'a']++;
```

to automatically update the counts of the letters 'a', 'b', 'c', and 'd' (assuming that's the only valid input). This one line will replace the four 'if' statements!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
char c;
int counta = 0;
int countb = 0;
int countc = 0;
int countd = 0;
char[] array = new char[4];
array[0] = 'a';
array[1] = 'b';
array[2] = 'c';
array[3] = 'd';

String line = new String();
while ((c = (char) reader.read()) != '\n') {

    if (c == array[0]) {
        counta++;
    }
    if (c == array[1]) {
        countb++;
    }
    if (c == array[2]) {
        countc++;
    }
    if (c == array[3]) {
        countd++;
    }
    line += c;
}
System.out.println(line);
System.out.println("a: " + counta);
System.out.println("b: " + countb);
System.out.println("c: " + countc);
System.out.println("d: " + countd);
```

This is simplier, and at the and it shows the string entered by the user and the count for each char.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call read(), it will accept a character from input. So store it in your variable c, and only call it when you're ready to accept another character (i.e. at the end of your loop). Also remember to check for an IOException:

```
try {
    c = (char)reader.read();  //read a character

    while (c != '\n') {   //check the character
        int x = 1+i;
        char[] cbuf = new char[x];
        cbuf[i] = c;

        if (cbuf[i]==array[0]){
            counta++;
        }
        if (cbuf[i]==array[1]){
            countb++;
        }
        if (cbuf[i]==array[2]){
            countc++;
        }
        if (cbuf[i]==array[3]){
            countd++;
        }
        System.out.println(cbuf);

        i++;
        c = (char)reader.read(); //ready to read another character
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```